# How can to count csv rows while writing data, instead of opening the file again with reader?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write data to a csv file and want to count the number of rows added while python is writing data.

```
def createCSV(usersession):
    filename = './usersession.csv'
    csvwrite = csv.writer(open(filename, 'w', newline=''))
    row_count = 0
    csvwrite.writerow(usersession['columnNames'])
    csvwrite.writerows(usersession['values'])
    with open(filename) as f:
        cr = csv.reader(f)
        for row in cr:
             row_count += 1
    return row_count
```

In the code I'm trying to open file again and I'm not sure if this is correct. If not, how could this be done?

Comment: Not sure what your data looks like, but what is wrong with `len(usersession['values'])`

Comment: Also, the `if row_count == 0` part is silly, you just set that variable to 0 and never changed it

Comment: true you can ignore that I have removed it.

Comment: data looks like this 

```values: [a, b, c, d], [1, 2, 3, 4,] ...```

each set is saving in one row

Comment: len(usersession['values']) - worked just fine, thanks

Comment: writerows() takes a list of lists, so I figured a len() would be your number of rows :)

Comment: Looks like your code writes `len(usersession['values']) + 1` rows.